# column value is varchar which needs to be converted to decimal. column name is in date format. sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `tblSample` which has columns names as date format value i.e. [202007], [202006]---[202001] and datatype is `varchar`.

I want to update another column(X) of `tblSample` with [202006]-[202005] and column(Y) with [202005]-[202004].
I am using below query which is giving output as 1 for all the records(around 50 records in `tblSample`).

```sql
    UPDATE tblSample          
    SET
    X = CAST(ISNULL(SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE(), 112), 6)), 0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) - CAST(ISNULL((SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE()), 112), 6)), 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
```

I am using `LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE(), 112), 6))` since the column name value will be updated everymonth to current month.

I have to convert to varchar to decimal since I am getting error saying subtraction cannot be performed on varchar values.

Where is that I am going wrong and will my update query, updates column-X and column-Y value correct for each row in the table

Values in columns of tblSample [2006]-3565.24, [2005]-3461.36, [2004]-3510.36.
Output

Thanks Shyam

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update using the column names:

```
update tblsamples
    set x = [202006]-[202005],
        y = [202005]-[202004] ;
```

Changing names in tables is a *really* bad idea.  You should instead have one row per month.  You can then easily calculate the difference using `lag()`:

```
select t.*, (value - lag(value) over (partition by ? order by yyyymm)) as diff
from t;
```

Perhaps re-pivoting if necessary.

If you are constructing the table each month, then you should construct the differences as well.  Or, perhaps more simply, just add columns called `latest_month` and `previous_month` and use those in the `update`.

Finally, if you are stuck with this format, you will need to use dynamic SQL.  That seems like a bad idea, though.

Comment: I have used dynamic sql to construct tblSample. I cannot add latest_month and previous_month in the tblSample while constructing it. Is there a option to convert varchar to decimal in the above shared query?